# Add time on ohmyzsh console on robbyrussell theme

Tags: oh-my-zsh

Very simple problem, i would like to see the time when i prompted my commands in the ohmyzsh console. I use the robbyrussell theme and would prefer to keep it if possible.

Thanks !

Comment: Do you mean the time should be ticking at prompt, but stay for some command executed above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
PROMPT="%D{%m/%f/%y}|%D{%L:%M:%S}"
```

See more at https://superuser.com/questions/943844/add-timestamp-to-oh-my-zsh-robbyrussell-theme/943916

Comment: working great, personaly prefer to have it on the right side so i used `RPROMPT`. Many thanks !